# Flip table in Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I'm looking to flip a table and can't seem to make it work with a combination of array formula and transpose. I'm looking for a formulae that can do this for larger data set

Please see the picture below for details.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oApg4.png)

Tried array formulas, transpose, pivot table but with no success

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please show a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with a [table](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) that shows your manually entered desired results, instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A1:C1&"×"&A2:C10); "×"); 
 "where Col2 is not null"; ))
```